# Does editing the axis2.xml file to include timeout parameters affect client stubs?

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm sure anyone familiar with Axis2 has seen this page a gazillion times:
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#timeout_config

I need a timeout on the client side, which seems like a fairly common requirement. The blurb on that page says you can edit the XML file, or add code to the client stubs. My understanding was that BOTH METHODS affect the client stubs, and I was expecting a difference in the generated stubs. After running a comparison, there was no difference in the stubs generated, with or without the timeout parameters in axis2.xml. So I would like to know what changing the XML file does, and if it affects the client stubs or if it is only meant for a deployment of Axis2 on a servlet.

Thank you in advance for your help! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says **timeout instances exist in the transport level**, that means it will have no effect on whatsoever wsdl or stub generated. Its just configures your services to timeout in given time over transport layer.

Just like, timeout tag in web.xml of a web application.